# Char String Assignment

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I am working on Microsoft Visual Studio environment. I came across a strange behavior

```
 char *src ="123";
 char *des ="abc";
 printf("\nThe src string is %c", src[0]);
 printf("\tThe dest string is %c",dest[0]);

 des[0] = src[0];

 printf("\nThe src string is %c", src[0]);
 printf("\tThe dest string is %c",dest[0]);
```

The result is:

```
1 a
1 a
```

That means the `des[0]` is not being initialized. As src is pointing to the first element of the string. I guess by rules this should work.

Comment: Please tag the question with the language, so people know what you are talking about.

Comment: If you're using C++, why in the world are you using `printf` and C-style strings?

Comment: @CodyGray: Sorry. I am using C language as platform. I have edited the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since src and des are initialized with string literals, their type should actually be `const  char *`, not `char *`; like this:

```
const char * src ="123";
const char * des ="abc";
```

There was never memory allocated for either of them, they just point to the predefined constants. Therefore, the statement `des[0] = src[0]` is undefined behavior; you're trying to change a constant there!

Any decent compiler should actually warn you about the implicit conversion from `const char *` to `char *`...

If using C++, consider using `std::string` instead of `char *`, and `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

Answer (score 4):

This is undefined behavior:

```
des[0] = src[0];
```

Try this instead:

```
char des[] ="abc";
```

Comment: Thank you. yes, it does work. But isn't it in both the cases, des would be pointing to the same location. And eventually 'des[0]' is equivalent to '*(des+0)'.  by undefined behavior, are you referring to the C specifications?

Comment: @vinaygarg It's not the same thing. Yes, I am talking about the C standard, but I expect the C++ standards to be similar in this respect.

Answer (score 2):

Section 2.13.4 of ISO/IEC 14882 (Programming languages - C++) says:

1. A string literal is a sequence of characters (as defined in 2.13.2) surrounded by double quotes, optionally beginning with the letter L, as in "..." or L"...". A string literal that does not begin with L is an ordinary string literal, also referred to as a narrow string literal. An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char” and static storage duration (3.7), where n is the size of the string as defined below, and is initialized with the given characters. ...
2. Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation defined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is **undefined**.

Answer (score 2):

In C, string literals such as `"123"` are stored as arrays of `char` (`const char` in C++). These arrays are stored in memory such that they are available over the lifetime of the program.  Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior; sometimes it will "work", sometimes it won't, depending on the compiler and the platform, so it's best to treat string literals as unwritable.

Remember that under most circumstances, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" whose value is the location of the first element in the array.

Thus, when you write

```
char *src = "123";
char *des = "abc";
```

the *expressions* `"123"` and `"abc"` are converted from "3-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`", and `src` will point to the `'1'` in `"123"`, and `des` will point to the `'a'` in `"abc"`.

Again, attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior, so when you write

```
des[0] = src[0];
```

the compiler is free to treat that statement any way it wants to, from ignoring it completely to doing exactly what you expect it to do to anything in between.  That means that string literals, or a pointer to them, cannot be used as target parameters to calls like `strcpy`, `strcat`, `memcpy`, etc., nor should they be used as parameters to calls like `strtok`.

Answer (score 1):

> **vinaygarg**: That means the `des[0]` is not being initialized. As src is pointing to the first element of the string. I guess by rules this should work.

Firstly you must remember that *src and *dst are defined as pointers, nothing more, nothing less.

So you must then ask yourself what exactly "123" and "abc" are and why it cannot be altered? Well to cut a long story short, it is stored in application memory, which is `read-only`. Why? The strings must be stored with the program in order to be available to your code at run time, in theory you should get a compiler warning for assigning a non-const `char*` to a `const char *`. Why is it `read-only`? The memory for exe's and dll's need to be protected from being overwritten somehow, so it must be read-only to stop bugs and viruses from modifying executing code.

So how can you get this string into modifiable memory?

```
// Copying into an array.
const size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
strcpy(buffer, "abc");
strncpy(buffer, "abc", BUFFER_SIZE-1);
```

Comment: @pmg My apologies, was not aware of C-only requirement at time of writing. Updated, thanks for pointing that out.